# jquery mobile list view Css issue when adding href link

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

For jquerymobile list view, I tried ui-grid-b for 3 columns. but CSS issues...[jsfiddle.net/9ZBAS/1](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZBAS/1) I tried and i could see columns overlapping if i use href and working fine if not using href but without href i couldnt get the next icon button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clip the overflowing text by using the following styles:

```
div {
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The right-arrow is added by JQM as part of its internal/auto styling of `<a>` links in `<li>`.

If you are not using `<a>`, you will have to manually add the arrow by doing something like this http://jsfiddle.net/nirmaljpatel/9ZBAS/2/

Comment: Actually i am going to use <a> link for the <li>, in that case what shall we do?

Comment: With <a> JQM will give you the right-arrow. For clipping off the text in child blocks; use the style I have mentioned above. What else do you need to achieve?